# How du get current ID from table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I write to a table in the database like this:

```
 var newOrder = new Orders
        {
            Orderdate = DateTime.Now,
            CustomersID = customerId.ID 
        };

        db.Orders.Add(newOrder);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a way to get the current auto incremented ID from table Orders?

Comment: What kind of _current_ id? The identity column of this table? Isn't it here: `db.SaveChanges(); int newID=newOrder.ID`

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's the auto incremented ID for each row.

Comment: Try newOrder.ID after save changes, it should have it.

Comment: What type of OR mapper is db? And what kind of database are you using?

Comment: @RononDex It'a a ASP.NET MVC application Entity Framwork Code First

Comment: Thanks all of you! newOrder.ID worked perfect!